# Cakephp 3 - in SSL submit post request is not recognized

Tags: cakephp, ssl

I have developed and deployed a website with Cakekphp 3.
My website was correctly working as http (without SSL), while in https the submit of a post request return false to the *if* control:

```
public function buy()
{
...
if ($this -> request -> is('post'))
...
}
```

I've to set

```
$this->Security->config('unlockedActions', ['buy']);
```

in the BeforeFilter(), disabling SSL in the *buy* action, but i prefer to have a post request with SSL for security reasons.

I used CSRF component, maybe is the problem related to a wrong usage of csrf? I used FormHelper in the view only with form tags and not with input tags.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: it's probably not post, but a get request; because you are redirecting from http to https somewhere. It is probably a much better idea to use https 100% of the time, not "sometimes".

Comment: Thank you for comment, the request is a post request (it doesn't pass parameters in the url), I also use tamper data to control and is not put or other type of request... the website is all in https, i force https inside cakephp and it works... the only problem is with post request.

Comment: You need to demonstrate that, not describe it.